# What is the difference between self and not self objects particularly in Tkinter class?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter, self

I have this simple code with self.btn1

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.btn1 = ttk.Button(self, text="test")
        self.btn1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

and this code without self button

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        btn1 = ttk.Button(self, text="test")
        btn1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Both of them work similarly, but what's the difference, which one should I use?

Comment: `self` is the instance you called the method on. Assignments to `self` (rather, whatever the *first* positional argument is, which is only *conventionally* called `self`) will create instance attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real difference lies in how easy it is to retrieve the reference to the `Button` instance should you need one. With the former, it's just `app.btn1`. With the latter, it's `app.winfo_children()[0]`.

```
>>> app.winfo_children()[0] is app.btn1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `btn1` is a local variable that is only available in the function in which it is used. `self.btn1` is an instance variable that is available in every function within the class.